# Cursor in wrong position in IE11 after CSS transform w/ transition

Tags: javascript, css, transform, internet-explorer-11, translate-animation

[jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/wmil/3arLjemp/)

This is a bug specific to IE and I'm looking for a work around.

When I apply a CSS `transform: translate` to a text input, that has the focus, with `transition` set to something valid, the cursor stays in the old location while the element moves.

Once you start typing it moves to the correct location, but before that the cursor stubbornly blinks at the old location.

This code illustrates the problem... again, it's an IE specific bug.

```js
var toggleTop = function(){
    $('.input-container').toggleClass('top');
    $('#the-input').focus();
}

$('#the-button').click(toggleTop);
```

```css
.input-container {
    top: 100px;
    left: 100px;
    position: fixed;
    transition: all 1s;
}

.input-container.top {
    transform: translateY(-100px);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='input-container'>
    <input type='text' id='the-input'></input>
</div>
<button id='the-button'>Click Me!</button>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is there any reason why you can't wait for the transition to end before focusing on the element? Considering you're using CSS transitions you should have access to `transitionend` event.
This fixes the issue:

```js
var toggleTop = function () {
    var inputContainer = $('.input-container'),
        input = inputContainer.find('#the-input');

    inputContainer.toggleClass('top');

    inputContainer.one('transitionend', function () {
        input.focus();
    });
};


$('#the-button').click(toggleTop);
```

[Updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3arLjemp/8/)

Answer (score 4):

One year passed, and I've encountered this issue as well. Here is angular.js directive that I used to fixed it, based on the accepted answer's code and explanation.

```
angular.module('my.directive')
  .directive('custom-auto-focus', function ($timeout) {
    return {
      link: function (scope, elm) {
        $timeout(function() {
          elm[0].focus();
        }, 350);
      }
    };
  });
```